# Why does Penrose expect visible Hawking Points in CMB?

Tags: cosmology, universe, space-expansion, cosmic-microwave-background

I've only just started reading into Conformal Cyclic Cosmology. My understanding of the hypothesis is that, with some conformal transformation of space, the very end of the universe at $t=\infty$ resembles the initial universe at $t=0$. Penrose speculates that evidence of the previous aeon may exist as circular structures imprinted on the CMB, structures called Hawking Points. (See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conformal_cyclic_cosmology) under "Empirical Tests".) He suggests that they are created from the evaporation or binary collisions of supermassive black holes. (See § 4 of this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1808.01740), "current observational status.")

My confusion is that the universe is supposed to expand to some arbitrarily huge size where it then "forgets" how huge it really is, becoming indistinguishable from being arbitrarily small. If that's the case, why expect gravitational waves from the previous universe at all?

Gravitational waves lose negligible energy to matter because the universe is mostly a void. They gradually dilute as they propagate, something to the tune of $1/r^2$ where $r$ is the distance from the source. On top of that, the universe is expanding, diluting the wave energy further, something to the tune of $1/a^4$ where $a$ is the expansion scale factor. All this would lend to some serious redshift of the wave. By $t=\infty$, intuitively, I'd expect the wave to be reduced to virtually nothing.

So, after infinite time and under CCC, why expect any gravitational evidence to cross over to the next aeon?

(If you have any suggestions for tags I'd love to hear them :)

Comment: comment to the last question, before reaching infinity, the gravitational field of your "mostly void" takes over . Also CMB is photons, electromagnetic waves. Just two  points that may help you with the model ( which I do not know)

Comment: @annav In your first sentence, I'm not sure what you mean; however, your second rings bells. Gravitational radiation is conformally scaled just like electromagnetic radiation, so that's why it crosses over aeons. I reckon I'll have to read more into the whole conformal scaling thing if I'm going to get a better understanding.

Comment: I mean the last sentence, before  the parenthetic end..I found a resume of Penrose theory, and that it is not mainstream. In the way I understand it, when only photons remain, he changes the scale of the universe, since photons are "static" and assumes all that energy is what will explode in another big bang, He also assumes that the peaks in the frequency photon  spectrum which the hawking radiation produced carry over, so that the  new CMB carries those peaks. It is a long shot and , together with mainstream thinking, I do not think it sis a viable model, or at least separable from the

Comment: peaks in cmb that mainstream assigns as seeds of galaxy clusters.

Comment: @annav Yeah, it is *definitely* not mainstream. My interests in it are for fiction writing and it is definitely a neat idea. Thank you for the input. I thought it was the present effects of the past aeon's gravitational radiation he was searching for, but it was instead the past effects. That will help me understand as I read further.